# Stochastic Gradient Descent (Momentum) Formula Implementation C++

Tags: algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

So I have an implementation for a neural network that I followed on Youtube. The guy uses SGD (Momentum) as an optimization algorithm and hyperbolic tangent as an activation function. I already changed the transfer function to Leaky ReLU (for the hidden layers) and Sigmoid (for the output layer).

But now I decided I should also change the optimization algorithm to Adam. And I ended up searching for SGD (Momentum) on Wikipedia for a deeper understanding of how it works and I noticed something's off. The formula the guy uses in the clip is different from the one on Wikipedia. And I'm not sure if that's a mistake, or not... The clip is one hour long, but I'm not asking you to watch the entire video, however I'm intrigued by the 54m37s mark and the Wikipedia formula, right here:

https://youtu.be/KkwX7FkLfug?t=54m37s
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Momentum

So if you take a look at the guy's implementation and then at the Wikipedia link for SGD (Momentum) formula, basically the only difference is in delta weight's calculation.

Wikipedia states that you subtract from the momentum multiplied by the old delta weight, the learning rate multiplied by the gradient and the output value of the neuron. Whereas in the tutorial, instead of subtracting the guy adds those together. However, the formula for the new weight is correct. It simply adds the delta weight to the old weight.

So my question is, did the guy in the tutorial make a mistake, or is there something I am missing? Because somehow, I trained a neural network and it behaves accordingly, so I can't really tell what the problem is here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen momentum implemented in different ways. Personally, I followed this guide in the end: http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent
There, momentum and weights are updated separately, which I think makes it clearer.

I do not know enought about the variables in the video, so I am not sure about that, but the wikipedia version is deffinetly correct.

In the video, the gradient*learning_rate gets added instead of subtracted, which is fine if you calculate and propagate your error accordingly.

Also, where in the video says "neuron_getOutputVal()*m_gradient", if it is as I think it is, that whole thing is considered the gradient. What I mean is that you have to multiplicate what you propagate times the outputs of your neurons to get the actual gradient.

For gradient descent without momentum, once you have your actual gradient, you multiply it with a learning rate and subtract (or add, depending on how you calculated and propagated the error, but usually subtract) it from your weights.

With momentum, you do it as it says in the wikipedia, using the last "change to your weights" or "delta weights" as part of your formula.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I have an idea on how to adapt this to Adam optimizer, because without asking on this same topic you answered one of my questions gradient related. I will take a look at that link and eventually run more tests on my network and come back if I face other problems.

Comment: Thanks for the website, explains it very well!